# Compare two bson_t in C / C++

Tags: c++, c, sorting, bson

I need to compare two bson_t. I found that two bson_t s may have different sequence of key-value pairs. for example {"key1": "val1", "key2" : "val2"} and {"key2": "val2", "key1" : "val1"}. But they are the same in my project. bson_compare() and bson_equal() will return false in this case. How to solve this problem in C/C++?

By the way, how to sort these key-value pairs in C or C++?

Thanks

Comment: C != C++. In general, you should pick *one*.

Comment: I pick C. In fact, I use libbson lib and mongodb c driver in my C++ project. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`bson_compare` and `bson_equal` check if two content buffers are equal (not only values @ two buffers (or memory locations)). It uses `memcmp` internally to compare two objects. Hence, `x==y` does not imply that `memcmp(x,y)==0`.

Comment: In document, it says "The _bson_compare()_ function shall compare two bson documents for equality. This can be useful in conjunction with _qsort()_." But I did not find _qsort()_ by GOOGLE. Does _qsort()_ sort the key-value pairs inside bson_t???

Answer (score 0):

Two methods:
(1) It is easy to do this in Python. Write a python function. And call this python function from C++ program.
(2) Using bson_iter_t to iterate each key-value pair in bson_t and do comparison recursively.

The second method seems more complex. But I decided to use it. Now, I already finished part of the method.